# Regex for simple pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string containing exactly one pair of parentheses (and some words between them), and lots of other words.

How would one create a regex to split the string into [ words before (, words between (), words after )]?

e.g.

```
line = "a   bbbb cccc     dd     ( ee fff ggg )    hhh iii jk"
```

would be split into

```
[ "a   bbbb cccc     dd", "ee fff ggg", "hhh iii jk" ]
```

I've tried

```
line = re.compile("[^()]+").split(line)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in the process you want to remove the leading and trailing whitespaces, i.e., the whitespaces before and after `(` and `)`. You could try:

```py
>>> line = "a   bbbb cccc     dd     ( ee fff ggg )    hhh iii jk"
>>> re.split(r'\s*[\(\)]\s*', line)
['a   bbbb cccc     dd', 'ee fff ggg', 'hhh iii jk']
>>>
>>> # to make it look as in your description ...
>>> line = re.compile(r'\s*[\(\)]\s*').split(line)
>>> line
['a   bbbb cccc     dd', 'ee fff ggg', 'hhh iii jk']
```

Answer (score 1):

To split the output in three I think the simplest option is to use three capture groups `(some_regex)(another_regex)(yet_another_regex)`. In your case, the first part is any character that is not a `(`, followed by `(`, then any character that is not `)` followed by `)` and finally followed by any character.

Therefore the regex is `([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)`, which you can then use to retrieve groups (your desired output):

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)')
>>> pattern.match(line).groups()
('a   bbbb cccc     dd     ', ' ee fff ggg ', '    hhh iii jk')
```

With:

- `([^(]*)` the first group
- `([^)]*)` the second group
- `(.*)` the last group